# jQuery gallery plugin to interface with Picasa

Tags: plugins, gallery

I'm looking for a specific type of gallery plugin implementation.

First of all, it needs to be able to pull from Picasa.

Second, I would like it to basically be a static lightbox...and what I mean by this is:

- Single image displayed with previous/next buttons
- Able to display the image title/description
- Able to display `Image <x> of <y>`
- Preferably make use of jQuery

At this point, I'd prefer to hide all gallery thumbnails and give the focus on the main image.  If thumbnails could be easily hidden and shown with a config option, that would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Picasa plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-picasa/screenshots/) i think it'll help you,or help to start a new plugin with some ideas..